# Solve summation

Tags: calculus, summation

I am wondering how one can solve generic 'summations' (or actually: if the idea I had to use integrals is correct):

To bring it to the point I have the following sum equation:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{19} \frac{1}{\epsilon}(b-ax_i) = 5$$
$$x_i = L\cdot (i + \frac{1}{2})$$
Here $b$ and $a$ are knowns, and I have to solve it and find the correct $\epsilon$ - and $x_i$ is simply the middle of a certain segment (each segment has the same length). The idea I had was just to find the integral to $x$, and change the limits such that the max is simply $x_{19} (=1.825\cdot19.5)$.

So:
$$\int_0^{19.5L} \frac{1}{\epsilon}(b-ax) dx =5$$
$$b\cdot19.5L + a \cdot 19.5^2L^2 = 5 \epsilon$$
$$\epsilon = 5.1L \cdot (b+a\cdot 19.5 L)$$

Edit, same problem, but even more "pressing/important" (notice especially the $i-1$ term):
$$\sum_0^{19}\delta_i + 2 \delta_{i-1}$$
$$\delta_i = a\cdot x_i = a \cdot L \cdot i$$
$$\delta_{i<0} = 0$$